# How to print set of user 's information in terraform output

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am writing terraform to create resource in AWS. When I try create a set of users, I have to print authenticate information to a file. The problem is in output file, terraform doesn't allow me use loop like `for i in length(my_user_set)` to print each user 's information.
Here is my variable.tf

```
variable "ops_list_username" {
    type = list(string)
    default = [ "ops_lincoln", "ops_trump", "ops_roosevelt" ]
  
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "create_ops_account" {
    
    count = length(var.ops_list_username)
    name = element(var.ops_list_username, count.index)
  
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "ops_account_access_keys" {
    count = length(var.ops_list_username)
    user = element(aws_iam_user.create_ops_account[*].name, count.index)


}

resource "aws_iam_user_login_profile" "ops_account_password" {
    count = length(var.ops_list_username)
    user = element(aws_iam_user.create_ops_account[*].name, count.index)



    password_length = 32
    password_reset_required = false
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [ password_length, ]
    }
  
}
```

So when I write output like

```
output "authenticate_list_account" {
    value = [ 
        {
            account = [
                {
                    "username" : aws_iam_user.create_ops_account[0].name,
                    "password" : aws_iam_user_login_profile.ops_account_password[0].password

                }
            ]
        }
        
    ]
        
}
```

the result in output exactly what I want for each user

```
"value": [
      {
        "account": [
          {
            "password": "O'uAj*]g0GV_g0UihP{Og[R_fGu(6(#9",
            "username": "ops_lincoln"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

but I want to print information of all user, so I make some change in previous code

```
output "authenticate_list_account" {
    value = [
        {
            account = [
                {
                    "username" : aws_iam_user.create_ops_account[*].name,
                    "password" : aws_iam_user_login_profile.ops_account_password[*].password
                }
               
            ]
        }
        
    ] 
        
}
```

the result will be

```
"value": [
      {
        "account": [
          {
            "password": [
              "O'uAj*]g0GV_g0UihP{Og[R_fGu(6(#9",
              "Id$Y|jmPr\u0026\u0026cTgbp@n1kEvQ6%H]UN1e^",
              "viN-Y++ei\u0026QgB}7Qgp+_iT$}{mMCi(rq"
            ],
            "username": [
              "ops_lincoln",
              "ops_trump",
              "ops_roosevelt"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

But what I really want will be look like

```
"value": [
  {
    "account": [
      {
        "password": "O'uAj*]g0GV_g0UihP{Og[R_fGu(6(#9",
        "username": "ops_lincoln"
      },
      {
        "password": "Id$Y|jmPr\u0026\u0026cTgbp@n1kEvQ6%H]UN1e^",
        "username": "ops_trump"
      },
      {
        "password": "viN-Y++ei\u0026QgB}7Qgp+_iT$}{mMCi(rq",
        "username": "ops_roosevelt"
      },

    ]
  }
]
```

So, how can I output exactly what I want with set of users instead a user.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outputting secrets into the console, is far from a good practice, because it is **insecure**. But if you insist of doing that, you have to iterate over your list:

```
output "authenticate_list_account" {
    value = [
        {
            account = [
              for idx in range(length(var.ops_list_username)):
                {
                  "password": aws_iam_user.create_ops_account[idx].name,
                  "username": aws_iam_user_login_profile.ops_account_password[idx].password
                }
            ]
        }        
    ] 
        
}
```

Comment: Thank for you support. I clearly understand output secret to console (or a file) is insecure. But according to my case, I really need that. Your answer is correct but need fix a little bit. In loop, range(length(ops_list_username)) must be range(length(var.ops_list_username)).